# Frequent Python2.7 Core dump

Tags: python, python-2.7, coredump

I have linux where python app is running but almost 1/2 month python2.7 crashes.
python based app is running as daemon and have threading to get work done.

Below is stack trace:

```
(gdb) bt
#0  __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at /usr/src/debug/glibc/2.24-r0/git/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:58
#1  0x00007f333c58838a in __GI_abort () at /usr/src/debug/glibc/2.24-r0/git/stdlib/abort.c:89
#2  0x00007f333c5c4ab0 in __libc_message (do_abort=do_abort@entry=2, fmt=fmt@entry=0x7f333c6b8b10 "*** Error in `%s': %s: 0x%s ***\n")
    at /usr/src/debug/glibc/2.24-r0/git/sysdeps/posix/libc_fatal.c:175
#3  0x00007f333c5cae86 in malloc_printerr (action=3, str=0x7f333c6b575b "free(): invalid size", ptr=<optimized out>, ar_ptr=<optimized out>)
    at /usr/src/debug/glibc/2.24-r0/git/malloc/malloc.c:5046
#4  0x00007f333c5cb67e in _int_free (av=0x7f333c8ebb20 <main_arena>, p=0x7f32f00041f0, have_lock=0)
    at /usr/src/debug/glibc/2.24-r0/git/malloc/malloc.c:3902
#5  0x00007f333c9ff359 in PyThread_ReInitTLS () from /usr/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0
#6  0x00007f333ca070f4 in PyOS_AfterFork () from /usr/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0
#7  0x00007f333ca0ad96 in ?? () from /usr/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0
#8  0x00007f333c9d663e in PyEval_EvalFrameEx () from /usr/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0
#9  0x00007f333c9d7b0c in PyEval_EvalCodeEx () from /usr/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0
#10 0x00007f333c9d6854 in PyEval_EvalFrameEx () from /usr/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0
#11 0x00007f333c9d7b0c in PyEval_EvalCodeEx () from /usr/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0
#12 0x00007f333c96288d in ?? () from /usr/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0
#13 0x00007f333c93b7f3 in PyObject_Call () from /usr/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0
#14 0x00007f333c94c4ba in ?? () from /usr/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0
#15 0x00007f333c93b7f3 in PyObject_Call () from /usr/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0
#16 0x00007f333c9960d7 in ?? () from /usr/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0
#17 0x00007f333c994c5e in ?? () from /usr/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0
#18 0x00007f333c93b7f3 in PyObject_Call () from /usr/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0
#19 0x00007f333c9d4af1 in PyEval_EvalFrameEx () from /usr/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0
#20 0x00007f333c9d7b0c in PyEval_EvalCodeEx () from /usr/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0
#21 0x00007f333c9d6854 in PyEval_EvalFrameEx () from /usr/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0
#22 0x00007f333c9d7b0c in PyEval_EvalCodeEx () from /usr/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0
#23 0x00007f333c96288d in ?? () from /usr/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0
#24 0x00007f333c93b7f3 in PyObject_Call () from /usr/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0
#25 0x00007f333c9d2ab0 in PyEval_EvalFrameEx () from /usr/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0
#26 0x00007f333c9d695e in PyEval_EvalFrameEx () from /usr/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0
#27 0x00007f333c9d695e in PyEval_EvalFrameEx () from /usr/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0
#28 0x00007f333c9d7b0c in PyEval_EvalCodeEx () from /usr/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0
#29 0x00007f333c9627bc in ?? () from /usr/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0
#30 0x00007f333c93b7f3 in PyObject_Call () from /usr/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0
#31 0x00007f333c94c4ba in ?? () from /usr/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0
#32 0x00007f333c93b7f3 in PyObject_Call () from /usr/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0
#33 0x00007f333c9d1317 in PyEval_CallObjectWithKeywords () from /usr/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0
#34 0x00007f333ca04f82 in ?? () from /usr/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0
#35 0x00007f333c33d3e4 in start_thread (arg=0x7f32fcff9700) at /usr/src/debug/glibc/2.24-r0/git/nptl/pthread_create.c:456
#36 0x00007f333c63bdef in clone () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/clone.S:105
(gdb) info threads
  Id   Target Id         Frame
* 1    Thread 0x7f32fcff9700 (LWP 443) __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at /usr/src/debug/glibc/2.24-r0/git/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:58
(gdb)
```

Anyone faced similar issue and have work around ??

Comment: You've had a buffer overflow that trashed heap memory.  Have you monitored the memory usage?  Is it possible it grew to large?  Are you using any C/C++ modules?

Comment: Its python app as I mention

Comment: Yes, but most Python apps import some modules that are in C or C++.  I'm not aware of any problems in pure Python that could cause this.  Unfortunately, Python 2.7 is no longer supported, so you can't get any official help.